# Error - username doesn't show when subscribing to AngularFireObject - Ionic 3 chat mobile application

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a simple chat application with Ionic 3 and Firebase. Registering, logging in users, sending, and displaying their messages work. This is a common chat room for all users.

I'd like a message to appear in the chat room when a user is logged in or logged out to let other users know. When test user is logged in, this message appears: 
"has joined the room"

When test user is logged out, this message appears: 
"test@gmail.com has left the room"

I'd like the username (email address) to show when the user is logged in as well. I'd like this message to appear: "test@gmail.com has joined the room"

I tried to write `this.username` on the console, but it doesn't write anything to the console.

**chat.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import $ from 'jquery';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {

  username: string= '';
  message: string= '';
  obsRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  obsToData: Subscription;
  messages: object[]= [];

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
      this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });

    this.obsRef = this.db.object('/chat');
    this.obsToData = this.obsRef.valueChanges().subscribe( data => {
      var data_array= $.map(data, function(value, index) {            
        return [value];
      });

      this.messages= data_array;
    });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      username: this.username,
      message: this.message
    }).then( () => {
      this.message= '';
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('user is about to go');
    this.obsToData.unsubscribe();

    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      specialMessage: true,
      message: `${this.username} has left the room`
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log(this.username);

    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      specialMessage: true,
      message: this.username + `has joined the room`
    })
  }
}
```

**chat.html:**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Chat</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<div id="chatMessages">
  <div *ngFor="let message of messages" [class]="message.specialMessage ? 'message special': 'message'">
    <div [class]="message.username == username ? 'innerMessage messageRight': 'innerMessage messageLeft'">
      <div class="username"> {{ message.username }} </div>
      <div class="messageContent"> {{ message.message }} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <div id="footer">
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "message"> </ion-input>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)= "sendMessage()">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: change your message from `${this.username} has joined the room`
 to `this.username +'has joined the room'`

Comment: I tried but the result is the same: this message appears: "has joined the room". The username doesn't show up. I checked and I can't even write this.username to the console with console.log. I changed the question's description.

Comment: `if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }` log your val here and check it comeing or not